# Recovered folders from Camera show as JPEG files and can can't be viewed

Tags: data-recovery

I have recovered a CCTV camera hard disk after a crash and have managed to get most of the data using EasyRecovery Pro. The problem is now that all the data that I have recovered appear like File09.JPG with and image icon in windows XP, but the files can't be viewed in any JPEG viewer software.

I suspect that the .JPG files are indeed folders, but I can't force windows XP the change the file type.

Very Odd.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Hoo

Comment: Is it in raw format?

Answer (score 1):

What format does the camera record in? Maybe it is supposed to be something else.

Use a hex-editor ([HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a good free one), to open some of the files and check that they are indeed JPG files (they should have the *JFIF* header).

Also, try running the files through a file-identification tool (a good, free one is [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)), to see exactly what file-type they are.

Finally, you could try using a different file-recovery program—you didn’t wipe the drive did you?—(a good, free one is [Photo-Rec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)). Open the drive in Photo-Rec, select JPG/AVI/(or maybe even all) for the file-type setting, and let it find the files for you (**make sure to select a different drive to recover to**).

Comment: Thanks a lot Synetech. I'll do as you suggested and see what happens.
The camera records in JPEG and then stitches them up to make a movie.

Hi Zoidberg, I did a raw recovery if that's what you mean.

Comment: @user69933, no, Zoidberg was asking if the camera saves images in RAW format as opposed to JPGs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format